# Android service in own thread is killed together with app process

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, process

I have a service declared in manifest like

```
        <service android:name=".services.ScreenOnService" android:process="@string/screenProcess"/>
```

all the service does is registering for Screen_on broadcast (As i always need the information that the Screen was turned on and not only if my app is running)

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    //All this service has to do is register for the screen on broadcast
    //as this one can't be registere in manifest and the ACTION_USER_PRESENT is
    //not guaranteed to be fired. (E.g. if no lock screen is used)
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(screenEventReceiver,filter);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    unregisterReceiver(screenEventReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I start the service from my Application onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if(!isScreenOnServiceAlreadyRunning())
    {
        //Start the screen on service
        Intent screenOnService = new Intent(this, ScreenOnService.class);
        startService(screenOnService);
    }
}
```

Everything is fine as long as the app is running. If I kill the app, the service in it's own process is also killed and I don't get why.

I found a promising article here http://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android and hoped the best but even if I do this and send a broadcast, it will not work.

Why does the service stop working if the app is killed? I assumed it will keep running, as it's in it's own process. If what I want is not realisable with my approach, what's the best way to do so?

Thanks already.

Comment: "If I kill the app" -- please explain **exactly** what you are doing to "kill the app".

Comment: I "kill" it on the device from Androids Task Manager.
I press the processes button and swipe the app off the screen.

Comment: "I press the processes button" -- there is no "processes button" in "Androids Task Manager" in standard Android. You are using something specific to your device. On some devices, this sort of advanced task manager does the equivalent of the user pressing Force Stop on your app's screen in Settings. In that case, your behavior is to be expected. This is an unfortunate decision on the part of those device manufacturers, and there is nothing that we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

@Hardcore_Graverobber I think you should start the service as a separate process,

please refer this tutorial
   http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought and what I'm doing.
But the process is stoppend with the app.